# How can I optimize this piece of code further?

Tags: python, optimization

Is it possible to use any loop optimization technique here to reduce the execution time in any way?

```
def get_destructors_in_radius(self, game_state, location, player_index=1):
    radius_locations = self.radius_locations_3(location)
    destructors = []
    for location2 in radius_locations:
        if location2 in self.all_locations:        
            unit = game_state.contains_stationary_unit(location2)
            if unit:
                if unit.unit_type == DESTRUCTOR and not unit.player_index == player_index:
                    destructors.append(unit)

    return destructors
```

Comment: This depends a lot on what `radius_locations_3` returns, how fast is `contains_stationary_unit`, how fast is `location2 in self.all_locations` and how many `DESTRUCTOR` units do you have comparing with `radius_locations` size.

Comment: What type is `self.all_locations`? Searching a long list is slow. Convert it to a `set` and this will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

If `self.all_locations` is a long list, convert it to a set to make lookups fast.

```
def get_destructors_in_radius(self, game_state, location, player_index=1):
    radius_locations = self.radius_locations_3(location)
    all_locations = set(self.all_locations)
    destructors = []
    for location2 in radius_locations:
        if location2 in all_locations:        
            unit = game_state.contains_stationary_unit(location2)
            if unit:
                if unit.unit_type == DESTRUCTOR and not unit.player_index == player_index:
                    destructors.append(unit)

    return destructors
```

Maybe you could make `self.all_locations` a set in the class itself, rather than converting it every time you call this function.

Other than that, there's not much that can be improved in this code. You might have to optimize the functions that it calls.

Comment: thanks for the answer, self.all_locations looks like so: [[6,7], [8,9], [5,1]], just alot longer. I'll try converting it into a set then

Comment: Actually I can't seem to convert it into a list, since it has lists in it.

Comment: a set I mean of course, any other ways? Can I make it a Tuple, would that speed it up?

Comment: Making it a list of tuples should allow you to put them in a set.